# Excel VBA Insert copied cells and shift cells down ERROR

Tags: excel, vba

Complete amateur here. I've been puzzling over this for hours, and I can't find anything to help me in any other thread. At my wit's end so sorry if this has been asked elsewhere.

I'm trying to create a ridiculously simple macro to do the following:

```
Go to Sheet2,
Select C6:C10
Copy
Go to Sheet3
Insert copied cells in B2 and shift the other cells down.
```

I did this just by recording the macro, but each time I do it, I get different errors. The error I currently have is 'Insert Method of Range Class Failed', but sometimes the error pops up at 'Selection.Copy'. This is the code I have:

```
Sub InsertCellsShitDown()
'
' InsertCellsShitDown Macro
'

'
Sheets("Booking Sheet").Select
Range("C6:C10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The errors are likely due to using the Select method. [It is advised to avoid using that statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Please remove the MACROS tag - it should not be used for VBA / MS-Office languages.

Comment: Maybe because the sub is called `ShitDown` :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub InsertCellsShiftDown()
'
' InsertCellsShitDown Macro
Dim bookingWS As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range

Set bookingWS = Sheets("Booking Sheet")
Set mainWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("C6:C10")

mainWS.Range("B2:B" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy mainWS.Range("B2")
End Sub
```

How does this work? I assume you wanted to insert 5 rows, so from `B2:B7`, then put the data.

Comment: This is completely bug-free (MASSIVE development!) but it shifts all rows down, which I don't want it to do.

The only cells I need to shift downwards are the rows directly below the cells I'm inserting. Does that make sense? I assume 'EntireRow' is the problem here.

Comment: @Knargle - Yah, check the edit (I just removed the `EntireRow` part)

Comment: Bingo. Thank you so much! I need to spend some time seriously learning this.

Comment: @Knargle - Happy to help! I suggest starting with [How to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) too.

Comment: Apologies for posting again, but I have another query that is very similar to my earlier one...

I want to do exactly the same thing but with a different starting range. Instead of C6:C10, I want to select all rows in column B below B2, UNTIL the first blank cell. Is that possible?

Comment: @Knargle - Try `Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("B2",Range("B2").End(xlDown))`

Comment: That brings up 'Method 'Range of Object'_Worksheet failed' error :/ the bug appears on the set copyRng line.

Comment: @Knargle oh sorry add `bookingWS.` before the second `Range()`